# VBA defining a range from an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

So I have a 2d array with 1000 rows and 10 columns. I want to create 10 ranges for each of the 10 columns and then use them as series to make a chart. MY question is, how do I define a range from an array, without using the entire array, just one column in it?

```
Sub ChartLord()

    Dim rows As Long
    Dim columns As Integer
    Dim mychart As Chart
    Dim data As Range
    Dim dataset() As Double

    rows = ShData.Cells(ShData.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    columns = ShData.Cells(1, ShData.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'set array range (includes column titles and xAxix column)
    dataset = ShData.Range(ShData.Cells(1, 1), ShData.Cells(rows, columns))



    For Z = 0 To 10

        Set data = ?
        Set mychart = shtCharts.Shapes.AddChart2(200, xlColumnClustered, 50 + 300 * Z, 50, 300, 200, 5).Chart


    Next Z



End Sub
```

Comment: You should understand that both **rows** and **columns** are reserved words in VBA and should not be used to name variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will collect your range values into a 2D range then slice off the second column into a new 2D array. The latter is simply 1 to 1 'column' wide.

```
Dim rws As Long, cols As Long, d As Long
Dim dataset() As Variant, subdataset() As Variant
Dim ShData As Worksheet

Set ShData = Worksheets("Sheet4")

rws = ShData.Cells(ShData.rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
cols = ShData.Cells(1, ShData.columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'set array range (includes column titles and xAxix column)
dataset = ShData.Range(ShData.Cells(1, 1), ShData.Cells(rws, cols))

subdataset = Application.Index(dataset, 0, 2) '<~~second column
For d = LBound(subdataset, 1) To UBound(subdataset, 1)
    Debug.Print subdataset(d, 1)
Next d

ShData.Cells(1, "Z").Resize(UBound(subdataset, 1), UBound(subdataset, 2)) = subdataset
```

The last operation puts the values of the peeled off column back into the worksheet starting at Z1.

Comment: thanks for that, would you be willing to chat with me in the chat forum on this site? I just have a few questions about graphing series in vba.